# Signal command in Alfresco Labs 3.0

Tags: alfresco

I was able to deploy and start a workflow through workflow-console. but when i tried to execute "`signal jbpm$2326535-@`" it gives me following error.

```
"org.alfresco.service.cmr.workflow.WorkflowException: Failed to signal transition 'null' from workflow path 'jbpm$2326535-@' "
```

Can anyone tell the reason and a solution for this please !

Comment: Custom workflow or a built in one? And have you thought about using a more recent version of Alfresco (3.0 is pretty old!)

Comment: Failed to signal transition is a generic error. We're not going to be able to help you without additional context and error messages. See if there are any other exceptions in the log.

Comment: i deployed following work flow definition which is taken from the "alfresco developer guide"  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<process-definition xmlns="urn:jbpm.org:jpdl-3.1"
name="helloWorld">
<start-state name="start">
<transition name="" to="hello"></transition>
</start-state>
<node name="hello">
<transition name="" to="end1">
<action class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.jbpm.
AlfrescoJavaScript">
<script>
logger.log("Hello World!");
</script>
</action>
</transition>
</node>
<end-state name="end1"></end-state>
</process-definition> i dont have any idea what is the rational behind this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your script code between `<![CDATA[` tags

Like:

```
<action class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.jbpm.AlfrescoJavaScript">
<script><![CDATA[
logger.log("Hello World!");
]]></script>
</action>
```

And for your own good add debugging in the log4j or add a seperate *log4j-dev.properties* in the alfresco/extension folder.
Set scriptlogger and other workflow elements to debug.

The reason why this happens, is that special characters like the exclamation mark needs to be put in a CDATA tag. for other characters like & there are escape characters like `&amp;`

Comment: Thankz again Friend :) It Worked !